# Acer A3-A40 Fastboot erase system, OEM not unlocked, not rooted, cannot find stock rom

Tags: fastboot

I erased the system with fasboot, now I cannot find the stock rom for it. What can I do ? There is no root and it is not OEM unlocked.

Answer (score 0):

The easieast way if your stock rom isn't available on the internet is to try multiple system.img files from different brands which have the same specs with your device (same SoC, same TP...).

Good luck!